# table with incomplete line

Tags: tables

This is probably very simple question: I am trying to generate a table with multiple rows in the last two columns. I have tried the following:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Type} \\
\hline
  & A  &    B & C & D \\
    \hline
    X & 53,2\%  &  51,6\%  &  \multirow{2}{*}{49\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{49\%} \\ 
    Y  & 53,8\%  &  52,2\%  &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But the table I get has an incomplete line down right:

[image]

How can I get a table with complete line? Is this the optimal way to generate such a table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot a ''&''

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Type} \\
\hline
  & A  &    B & C & D \\
    \hline
    X & 53,2\%  &  51,6\%  &  \multirow{2}{*}{49\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{49\%} \\ 
    Y  & 53,8\%  &  52,2\%  & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The last row misses the last `&`. The rightmost line is only set, if the last cell is used. An empty last cell will do:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Type} \\
\hline
  & A  &    B & C & D \\
    \hline
    X & 53,2\%  &  51,6\%  &  \multirow{2}{*}{49\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{49\%}
 \\
    Y  & 53,8\%  &  52,2\%  &  & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]